# angular - strange error 'Cannot read property then of undefined' when one of the arguments is an empty array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the line that is throwing the problem:

```
submitInfo(groups, $scope.Tab, other, drug, "Saved", false)
                .then(function () {
                })
```

The strange thing is that that submitInfo (which is an injected service) is recognized (I set a break point there). This error only gets thrown when groups is an empty array. I don't understand why this is happening or how to prevent it. I would like the function to execute even when groups is empty.

here is submitInfo:

```
summariesApp.factory('submitInfo', ['$http', '$q', 'validate', 'getInfo', '$rootScope', 'toaster', function ($http, $q, validate, getInfo, $rootScope, toaster) {
    return function (groups, Tab, other, drug, state, auto) {        
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        if (groups.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (state != "Saved") {
            if (!validate(groups, Tab, other, drug, "submit")) {
                return;
            }
        }

        var deferral = $q.defer();

        $http({
            url: "ThirtySecond.aspx/SubmitSummary",
            method: "POST",
            data: { type: Tab, groups: groups, summaryState: state, other: other, drug: drug },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' }
        })
        .success (
            function () {

                getInfo(Tab, other, drug)
                .then(function (data) {
                    var newGroups = data;
                    for (i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
                        var group = groups[i];
                        var newGroup = $rootScope._.find(newGroups, 'Grouptype', group.Grouptype);
                        newGroup.show = group.show;
                        newGroup.Checked = group.Checked;
                    }

                    switch (state) {
                        case "Saved":
                            if (auto) {
                                successMessage = "Auto Saved";
                            }
                            else {
                                successMessage = "Saved";
                            }
                            break;
                        case "SubmittedForReview":
                            successMessage = "Submitted for review";
                            break;
                        case "NoSummaryWarranted":
                            successMessage = "Summary updated as 'No Summary Warranted'";
                            break;
                        case "FinalizedButNotRolledOut":
                            successMessage = "Summary updated as 'Finalized but not ready to roll out'";
                            break;
                        case "Finalized":
                            successMessage = "Summary finalized";
                            break;
                        default:
                            successMessage = "Draft Entered";
                    }
                    toaster.pop('success', "Updated", successMessage);

                    angular.extend(groups, newGroups);
                    deferral.resolve(true);
                })                
            }
        )
        .error(
            function () {
                toaster.pop('error', "Error!", "Something went wrong. Please contact the administrator.");
                deferral.reject(true);
            }
        )
        return deferral.promise;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Apparently `submitInfo` is returning `undefined` when `groups` is an empty array. What does `submitInfo` return otherwise?

Comment: @Siguza It is a function which returns a promise.

Comment: Could you show "submitInfo" code?

Comment: @victork added it to the post.

Comment: You aren't returning a promise when group is 0.

Comment: @pquestions123 please change title - this is not „strange error”. You can’t call `.then()` on undefined. `var deferred = $q.defer()` and `var deferral = $q.defer();` are you sure?

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Thanks, that is another bug. What would you suggest the title be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`submitInfo` is returning `undefined` as a result of the `return;` statement used in

```
if (groups.length == 0)
{
    return;
}
```

Replace all `return;`'s by `return deferred.promise;` (since `deferral` is not yet available) and your code should work.

In case you couldn't change `submitInfo`, you could also build a fallback when calling the function using `||` (based on the fact that `undefined` evaluates to `false`):

```
(submitInfo(groups, $scope.Tab, other, drug, "Saved", false) || /* get your promise here */)
            .then(function () {
            })
```

(I'm not entirely sure, would the code to get the promise be `$scope.Tab.defer().promise` or does `summariesApp.factory` mess up the parameters?)

Comment: Thanks, I replaced it with return $q.when(true); It is working now.

Comment: @pQuestions123 Don't forget to do that with the state check also right below this one.

Comment: @MatthewGreen good call, I just realized I had a bunch of spots like this in the code. Saved me a lot of headache.